# Insert values in to a 2D array VB.Net using dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take data from a table in a database and put it in to an array, then input the data in to a different table in the database. I am having difficulty using a 2D array with the dataset.

In the code below, adding to the Hname column the value of `names(i,0)` works perfectly. However, when the next line is executed, names(j,0) does not work but if i swap it to `names(0,j)` it inserts the first value in the array ie. value at position 0. I cannot figure out why trying to insert the value at j does not work.

```
Dim count As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
Dim names As String(,) = New String(count - 1, 4) {}
For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To count - 1

        names(i, j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()

        Dim myconnectone As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        myconnectone.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim mycommandone As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
        mycommandone.Connection = myconnectone
        mycommandone.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Matches (HomeTeam,AwayTeam) VALUES (@Hname,@Aname)"
        myconnectone.Open()
        mycommandone.Parameters.Add("@Hname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = names(i, 0)
        mycommandone.Parameters.Add("@Aname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = names(0, j)
        mycommandone.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
Next
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your example, the array is kind of pointless since you are inserting each items on at a time. You could also do everything in the database with a INSERT INTO matches (...) SELECT ... FROM [table name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs tidying but try

```
Dim count As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
Dim ColCount As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count
Dim names As String(,) = New String(count - 1, 4) {}
For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To ColCount - 1

        names(i, j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()

    Next
    Dim myconnectone As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnectone.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim mycommandone As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    mycommandone.Connection = myconnectone
    mycommandone.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Matches (HomeTeam,AwayTeam) VALUES (@Hname,@Aname)"
    myconnectone.Open()
    mycommandone.Parameters.Add("@Hname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = names(i, 0)
    mycommandone.Parameters.Add("@Aname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = names(i, 1)
    mycommandone.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```